# Difference/similarities between xsd:any and xsd:anyType

Tags: xml, xsd

I am reading about XML, XML-Schema, DTD and I don't really understand the difference between **xsd:any** and **xsd:anyType**.

Can someone explain this to me or point to some good article? (please don't link to the XML-Schema specifications - I read that and I'm more confused)

TIA

Answer (score 34):

[This post](http://lists.xml.org/archives/xml-dev/200703/msg00163.html) explains it nicely. I quote:

> xsd:anyType is a type, like
>   xsd:integer (though xsd:anyType is
>   special in that it can act as a simple
>   or complex type, and it places
>   essentially no restrictions on the
>   tree that it validates -- think of it
>   loosely as the Schema language's
>   analog of java.lang.Object).
>
> A sample use would be:

```
<xsd:element name="e" type="xsd:anyType"/>
```

> This would mean that elements named
>   `<e>` can have any content, any
>   attributes, etc.
>
> xs:any is a wildcard, usable as a term
>   in a content model.  For example:

```
<xsd:complexType name="T">
  <xsd:sequence>
    <xsd:element ref="A"/>
    <xsd:any />
    <xsd:element ref="C"/>
  </xsd:sequence>
</xsd:complexType>
```

> Elements of type T must have content
>   `<A/><???/><C/>`, where `<???>` can be
>   any named element. Now, if you look
>   really closely there is an
>   approximation to the definition of
>   xsd:anyType given for reference in the
>   Recommendation, and it uses an xsd:any
>   wildcard as the means of saying that
>   it allows any elements.

Also take a look at the [XML Schema](http://www.w3.org/TR/xmlschema-0/#anyType).

Comment: So **anyType** is more restrictive than **any**? In the sense that in the first example I must have element <e> with whatever content, while in the second case I can have whatever element (i.e. not restricted to the <e> tag name)? Is that it? **anyType** imposes an extra constraint on the name of the element?

Comment: @user989812323 yes, you're right. With `any` you can have whatever element you want.

Comment: Note:  xsd:anyType  is parent of all simple or complex types so it's the DEFAULT type. So <xsd:element name="e" type="xsd:anyType"/> is equal to <xsd:element name="e" />

Answer (score 31):

The mailing list post linked in dogbane's answer wasn't clear to me until I created the following example:

With anyType schema:

```
<xsd:complexType name="Outer">
    <xsd:element name="e" type="xsd:anyType" />
</xsd:complexType>
```

Which allows this format:

```
<Outer>
    <e> // must be called "e"
        // but anything can go inside
    </e>
</Outer>
```

And with any schema:

```
<xsd:complexType name="Outer">
    <xsd:any />
</xsd:complexType>
```

Which allows this format:

```
<Outer>
    //anything can go inside
</Outer>
```

So anyType is a type, and any is an element