# Xml Xsd Validation Fails (xs:anyType)

Tags: c#, .net, xml, xsd, xml-validation

I have this **XML** file

```
<bookstore>  
  <test>
    <test2/>
  </test>
</bookstore>
```

and this **XSD** schema

```
<xsd:schema xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
  <xsd:element name="bookstore" type="bookstoreType"/>     
  <xsd:complexType name="bookstoreType">
    <xsd:sequence maxOccurs="unbounded">  
      <xsd:element name="test" type="xsd:anyType" />
    </xsd:sequence>                                       
  </xsd:complexType>
</xsd:schema>
```

I intend to validate xml file from C# code.
There is a method that validate XML file:

```
    // validate xml
    private void ValidateXml()
    {
        _isValid = true;

        // Get namespace from xml file
        var defaultNamespace = XDocument.Load(XmlFileName).Root.GetDefaultNamespace().NamespaceName;

        // Set the validation settings.
        XmlReaderSettings settings = new XmlReaderSettings();
        settings.ValidationType = ValidationType.Schema;
        settings.ValidationFlags |= XmlSchemaValidationFlags.ReportValidationWarnings;
        settings.Schemas.Add(defaultNamespace, XsdFileName);
        settings.ValidationEventHandler += OnValidationEventHandler;

        // Create the XmlReader object.
        using(XmlReader reader = XmlReader.Create(XmlFileName, settings))
        {
            // Parse the file. 
            while (reader.Read()) ;    
        }
    }

    private void OnValidationEventHandler(object s, ValidationEventArgs e)
    {
        if (_isValid) _isValid = false;

        if (e.Severity == XmlSeverityType.Warning)
            MessageBox.Show("Warning: " + e.Message);
        else
            MessageBox.Show("Validation Error: " + e.Message);
    }
```

I know, this XML file is valid. But my code reterns this Error:

```
Validation Error: Could not find schema information for the element 'test2'
```

Where is my mistake?

Thanks!!!

Comment: look at this question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5389076/difference-similarities-between-xsdany-and-xsdanytype

Answer (score 1, accepted):

UPDATE: I assume your code matches the error you listed (I've tried your code on .NET 3.5SP1, and I wasn't able to reproduce your behaviour). The workaround below should work for sure (the error you're getting is consistent to a process contents clause `strict` as opposed to `lax`).

Replace `<xsd:element name="test" type="xsd:anyType" />` with a complex content that allows for xsd:any, like this:

```
<xsd:schema xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"> 
    <xsd:element name="bookstore" type="bookstoreType"/> 
    <xsd:complexType name="bookstoreType"> 
        <xsd:sequence maxOccurs="unbounded"> 
            <xsd:element name="test">
                <xsd:complexType>
                    <xsd:sequence>
                        <xsd:any minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded" processContents="lax"/>
                    </xsd:sequence>
                </xsd:complexType>
            </xsd:element>
        </xsd:sequence> 
    </xsd:complexType> 
</xsd:schema>
```

Having "lax" will still yield a message; you could use "skip" if you want that message gone. Regardless, `skip` and `lax` in an xsd:any gives you what you need.

Comment: I'm a little surprised that you accepted this answer. It might be a workaround, but it doesn't explain why the original failed. I'm therefore downvoting. As you rightly point out, your XML instance is valid against your XSD schema, and I for one can't see why it should fail.

Comment: @MichaelKay, I agree that the answer is not explicitly stating one thing: that I've provided a workaround for what might be a bug or coding error.